# Why the `mongod` command doesn't show the message "waiting for connections on port 27017" at the end of its returned result

Tags: database, mongodb

I've just started learning MongoDB on my Mac, and now facing a problem.
In the online course that I'm taking, I learnt when we run the command `mongod`, we can see the result that says `waiting for connections on port 27017` at the end, and it means "you are ready to use MongoDB.

However, when I ran the command, I received the different result that I show below, and came back to the prompt. Can I ignore this? Or is something wrong happening?

By the way, I was able to run the other command `mongo` in a new shell and use the MongoDB with no problems.

```
% mongod
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.824+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.829+09:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.829+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.829+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":13253,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"YusukesMBP.orihime.ne.jp"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.829+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.3","gitVersion":"913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.829+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.2.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.829+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.831+09:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.831+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.831+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.831+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.831+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-13T10:40:20.832+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
%
```

Answer (score 0):

The log output you got is called "structured log output" and is the only log format of MongoDB as of 4.4. Previous versions used the human-readable log format.

Additionally, your log output contains an error, which is why the server didn't log that it was waiting for connections (and in fact was not waiting for connections).

Comment: Thank you kindly. How do you think I can solve it?